# Tracking of hybrid (Flutter) app with Google Analytics: Aggregation of iOS and Android stats possible?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-analytics, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to integrate Google Analytics in our hybrid app (iOS and Android).

We're using Flutter.

When setting up a property for app tracking in Google Analytics it prompts me to either choose IOS or Android app.

What do I choose and will I be able to see aggregated data (audience, users, funnel, dashboard, etc.), or do I have to set up a property for iOS and Android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both, as when you compile and publish them they will be 2 individual apps.

You will be able to see aggregated data.